# Maximum likelihood estimator and KL divergence

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, kullback-leibler

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a continuous random vector, $\mathbf{d}$ a sample of size $m$, and $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{\theta}}$ a parametric model for the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$.

We can write the likelihood of the sample under this parametric model as:

$f(\mathbf{d}|\mathbf{\theta}) = \exp\left[-mH_\lambda(\hat{\mathbb{P}}_m||\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{\theta}})\right]$

where $\hat{\mathbb{P}}_m$ is the empirical distribution and
$H_\lambda(\hat{\mathbb{P}}_m||\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{\theta}})$ is the cross-entropy between $\hat{\mathbb{P}}_m$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{\theta}}$ relatively to the Lebesgue measure.

Now, in the infinite sample limit, we have that $\hat{\mathbb{P}}_m \xrightarrow[m \to +\infty]{} \tilde{\mathbb{P}}_{\mathbf{X}}$ where $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_{\mathbf{X}}$ is the unknown distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ that generated the sample.

Using the fact that $H_\lambda(\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_{\mathbf{X}}||\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{\theta}}) = H_\lambda(\tilde{\mathbb{P}}_{\mathbf{X}}) + D_{KL}(\tilde{P}_{\mathbf{X}}||\mathbb{P}_{\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{\theta}})$, in this limit, maximizing the likelihood is minimizing the KL divergence between the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ and the parametric model.

As it has been asked in this thread ([Maximum likelihood and Minimizing Kullback–Leibler divergence to the ecdf?! (i.e.: finite sample statement?)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445062/maximum-likelihood-and-minimizing-kullback-leibler-divergence-to-the-ecdf-i-e)), is it possible to have the same statement but in the finite sample case ? I think I agree with this answer but it has been pointed in two other threads (([Maximum likelihood as minimizing the dissimilarity between the empirical distriution and the model distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/434749/maximum-likelihood-as-minimizing-the-dissimilarity-between-the-empirical-distriu)) and ([Kullback–Leibler divergence when one measure is a sum of diracs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350321/kullback-leibler-divergence-when-one-measure-is-a-sum-of-diracs))), that the section 5.5 of *Deep Learning, Ian Goodfellow* (https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html) states that it is possible.

I would like to use the formula that links the cross-entropy and the KL divergence but I guess it is not well defined when we use the empirical distribution in place of the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$.